# Hibernate Equi join issue

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

I'm trying to achieve equi join using hibernate. Please see the sql `select v.version_id from product p, version v where p.productid=v.product_id and p.name='stack'`

its one-to-one relationship  and i want to get the version id using productname.

product table:

```
productid;
name;
```

productversion table:

```
version_id;
productid;
date;
```

Thank you

Comment: Show us your entities.

Comment: Your SQL query doesn't make much sense. Why would a person have the same ID as a passport? What do you really want the query to retrieve? And why do you have a set of passports in Passport?

Comment: I apologies for previous bad example.Its the reason you got confusion.I've edited the questions, i hope now you make sense.

Comment: And now you removed your entities once again. HQL and Criteria queries use thge entities and their associations. We can't tell how to create a query without this information. ust like you can't tell how to create a SQL query without knowing the tables.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a typical one-to-many relationship:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#example.collection.mapping.annotations